# Understanding polygonize tool- QGIS 2.14

Tags: raster, vector, convert, polygonize, qgis-2.14

I tried to convert all the roads (red) from this raster into vector:

[image]

but when i use the convert tool- Polygonize, i get this result:

[image]
[image]

whereas, i expect to  get all the roads with single clear DN/ RGB.
 How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

To extract road network from topographic map in a clean way, although time consuming, is to digitize the map. Using polygonize tool will not give you the desired output since the map is in RGB color (3 bands) format and not one band.

Another better way is to find a digital source of the road network in vector format such as [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/) and download the road network of the target area.

Comment: Software R2V can polygonize exact color on map.

Comment: But he is talking about polygonize tool in QGIS. If he has access to R2V software or ArcScan extension in ArcGIS, it may give better results. However he still needs to clean the data which will consume a lot of time. In my opinion and experience, digitizing is faster. Or if he can get data in vector format like from OSM, it will be much better.